# Telegram bot keyboard resize_keyboard in php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am working on a telegram bot using php, I want to resize my ReplyKeyboardMarkup button to fit each of the keyboards.

I want the first button to take the full width of the keyboard and the second and fourth button takes the middle then I want the last button to take the entire width at the bottom.

This is my code.

```
        $replyMarkup = array(
          'keyboard' => array(
              array("Get all foods", "Menu" "List", "Cancel")
          ),
          'resize_keyboard' => true
      );
      // checking if this user has already login in before
          $useit = json_encode($replyMarkup);
          $parameters = array(
              "chat_id" => $user_id,
              "parseMode" => "html",
              "text" => "Select country code",
              "reply_markup" => $useit
          );
        send("sendMessage", $parameters);
```

How can I resize each of my buttons using `'resize_keyboard' => true`

Answer (score 2):

you can make your keyboard structure with arrays
for example:

```
$replyMarkup = array(
     'keyboard' => array(
          array("Get all foods"),
          array("Menu", "List"),
          array("Cancel")
     ),
     'resize_keyboard' => true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send it via "`sendMessage`?" then in `json` it should look like this:

```
{"chat_id": "1234567890", "text": "messagetext123", "reply_markup": {"keyboard":[[{"text":"button1"},{"text":"button2"}]], "resize_keyboard":true}
```

Boolean in resize_keyboard MUSTN't be in braces.